# Framework similar to Prism for Knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, prism, durandal

Microsoft made Prism framework for Silverlight and WPF. It looks great with its RegionManager and other stuff.

Is there any similar framework for Knockout?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at http://boilerplatejs.org? It's a reference architecture you may use for SPA, and supports knockoutjs too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rob Eisenberg, the developer of [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) (IMO the best MVVM framework available for XAML apps) is developing Durandal which uses Knockout.

An early version of the source is [here](https://github.com/EisenbergEffect/Durandal), and you can read a little bit about the design concept [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2012/08/02/today-all-your-wildest-dreams-come-true.aspx).

Comment: Durandal is a much leaner, meaner, trimmer framework than Prism. But it is quite robust.

Comment: Trying to find and docs on durandal is challenging , wiki is a bit light. Anyone recommend a good place to get started, or an intro?

Comment: Download the source from GitHub and then you can either run the root solution file (just modify the main.js to point to the different samples there) or you can start with the vs template. It is a bit hard to find in the source, but it is under skeletons\vstemplate\DurandalTemplate.

Comment: The wiki and the samples in github are the best right now. Soon there will be a Pluralsight course that covers it, too (March 1st +/-).

Comment: Looks like official Durandal documentation has been released: http://durandaljs.com/pages/docs